# Haskell type with derived value

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to have a type preform a function one of its value to generate another one of it's values? For instance:

```
data Foo=Foo {valueOne::Int, valueTwo=valueOne*2} deriving (Bar)
```

Or am I thinking about this in the wrong way? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: well that would be the same as having a function `valueTwo :: Foo -> Int` (`valueTwo = (*2) . valueOne`) anyway wouldn't it? (and no this is not possible - you would not want it anyway as you can say `Foo 2 3` to create a value of type `Foo` which would be *wrong*)

Comment: BTW: this `Foo` `deriving Bar` stuff *smells* of OOP ;) (no offense - just joking)

Comment: Well I come from OOP :D. My question I guess would then be, what about when we have some datatype where it makes sense that a third value would be derived? `data Square=Square {sides::Int, area::Int}`. It seems like we would want area to be part of that package, even though it is a derived value.

Comment: I could very well be talking crazy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you *always* want the second field to depend on the first, just write a plain function:

```
data Foo = Foo { valueOne :: Int } deriving (Bar)

valueTwo :: Foo -> Int
valueTwo x = valueOne x * 2
```

The only difference is that the `Bar` instance, which is automatically generated, won't notice the second field.

If, instead, you want to *generate* values with such constraint, but still be able to sometimes disregard that, use a *smart constructor*:

```
data Foo = Foo { valueOne :: Int, valueTwo :: Int } deriving (Bar)

foo :: Int -> Foo
foo x = Foo x (2 * x)
```

If you use `foo` instead of `Foo` to construct new values, you will not need to pass the second argument, which will be derived from the first one.

Usually this is used in a `module` which does not export the constructor `Foo`, but exports the smart constructor `foo`. In this way the users of the module are constrained to build values satisfying the invariant, while the functions in the module can ignore it, when needed.

Comment: Ah! This makes sense. Is this something that I shouldn't be doing though?

Comment: @Slimemold I don't think there are significant problems with this approach -- it's not extremely frequent, but I guess it's quite idiomatic. E.g. `Data.Rational` uses this to disallow non-normalized fractions. Whether you should do this or not ultimately depends on your goal, of course.

Comment: (The actual module name is `Data.Ratio`)